# Error loading my managedObjectModel

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

When I call [myAppDelegate managedObjectModel], in the retain line below, my application will crash (iPhone SDK v3.1.3):

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Here is my crash trace

```
#0  0x905c44e6 in objc_exception_throw
#1  0x01e78c3b in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:]
#2  0x01e78b9a in +[NSException raise:format:]
#3  0x000af99b in _NSArrayRaiseInsertNilException
#4  0x0001c360 in -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]
#5  0x0001c274 in -[NSCFArray addObject:]
#6  0x01c16a7e in +[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:]
#7  0x00002432 in -[myAppDelegate managedObjectModel] at myAppDelegate.m:102
```

What is going on here? This is template code that I haven't seen fail before.

Cheers

Nik

Comment: If you look in the Console they tend to output the exception text and other useful things. This will let us know what type of exception occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the text that goes with that crash?  You probably have duplicate entities or it is failing to find the model at all.

### update

To be clear, the extension for a single file should be `.xcdatamodel`.  `.xcdatamodeld` is meant for versioned bundles.

Comment: Hi Marcus, you were very right, it's failing to find the model. My model extention was .xcdatamodel, not .xcdatamodeld. As soon as I switched to a .xcdatamodeld it was all working fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have as the default implementation:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
}
return managedObjectContext;
```

`}`